# extending an object with an interface through an object expression

Tags: f#

Is it possible to decorate an object in F# with an interface using an object expression. E.g.:

```
type IFoo = abstract member foo : string
type IBar = abstract member bar : string
let a = { new IFoo with member x.foo = "foo" }

/// Looking for a variation on the below that does compile, the below doesn't
let b = { a with
             interface IBar with
                 member x.Bar = "bar" }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't extend an object with an interface at run-time, but you could wrap it with another object:

```
let makeB (a: IFoo) = 
    { 
        new IFoo with
            member x.foo = a.foo
        interface IBar with
            member x.bar = "bar" 
    }


let a = { new IFoo with member x.foo = "foo" }
let b = makeB a
```

Comment: thank you, that answered the question, though it wasn't the answer I was hoping for. I now have to rethink my design. Is stackoverflow the place for questions on that, or should I go somewhere else?

Comment: link to my follow uop question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24645007/design-alternatives-to-extending-object-with-interface