# Design alternatives to extending object with interface

Tags: f#

While working through Expert F# again, I decided to implement the application for manipulating algebraic expressions. This went well and now I've decided as a next exercise to expand on that by building a more advanced application.

My first idea was to have a setup that allows for a more extendible way of creating functions without having to recompile. To that end I have something like:

```
type IFunction =
    member x.Name : string with get
    /// additional members omitted

type Expr =
    | Num of decimal
    | Var of string
    ///... omitting some types here that don't matter
    | FunctionApplication of IFunction * Expr list
```

So that say a Sin(x) could be represented a:

```
let sin = { new IFunction() with member x.Name = "SIN" }
let sinExpr = FunctionApplication(sin,Var("x"))
```

So far all good, but the next idea that I would like to implement is having additional interfaces to represent function of properties. E.g.

```
type IDifferentiable =
     member Derivative : int -> IFunction // Get the derivative w.r.t a variable index
```

One of the ideas the things I'm trying to achieve here is that I implement some functions and all the logic for them and then move on to the next part of the logic I would like to implement. However, as it currently stands, that means that with every interface I add, I have to revisit all the IFunctions that I've implemented. Instead, I'd rather have a function:

```
let makeDifferentiable (f : IFunction) (deriv : int -> IFunction) =
    { f with
        interface IDifferentiable with
            member x.Derivative = deriv }
```

but as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641886/extending-an-object-with-an-interface-through-an-object-expression), that is not possible. The alternative that is possible, doesn't meet my extensibility requirement. My question is what alternatives would work well?

[EDIT] I was asked to expand on the "doesn't meet my extenibility requirement" comment. The way this function would work is by doing something like:

```
let makeDifferentiable (deriv : int -> IFunction)  (f : IFunction)=
    { new IFunction with
          member x.Name = f.Name
      interface IDifferentiable with
          member x.Derivative = deriv }
```

However, ideally I would keep on adding additional interfaces to an object as I add them. So if I now wanted to add an interface that tell whether on function is even:

```
type IsEven =
    abstract member IsEven : bool with get
```

then I would like to be able to (but not obliged, as in, if I don't make this change everything should still compile) to change my definition of a sine from

```
let sin = { new IFunction with ... } >> (makeDifferentiable ...)
```

to

```
let sin = { new IFunction with ... } >> (makeDifferentiable ...) >> (makeEven false)
```

The result of which would be that I could create an object that implements the IFunction interface as well as potentially, but not necessarily a lot of different other interfaces as well; the operations I'd then define on them, would potentially be able to optimize what they are doing based on whether or not a certain function implements an interface. This will also allow me to add additional features/interfaces/operations first without having to change the functions I've defined (though they wouldn't take advantage of the additional features, things wouldn't be broken either.[/EDIT]

The only thing I can think of right now is to create a dictionary for each feature that I'd like to implement, with function names as keys and the details to build an interface on the fly, e.g. along the lines:

```
let derivative (f : IFunction) =
    match derivativeDictionary.TryGetValue(f.Name) with
    | false, _ -> None
    | true, d  -> d.Derivative
```

This would require me to create one such function per feature that I add in addition to one dictionary per feature. Especially if implemented asynchronously with agents, this might be not that slow, but it still feels a little clunky.

Comment: Can you clarify what about the wrapper type doesn't meet your extensibility requirements? If you implemented both IFunction and IDifferentiable on the object, it would be very similar to what I imagine the { f with ... } syntax would do, so I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Try looking at Type Classes implementations in F#. I'm on my,phone, so I won't write an elaborate answer, but take a look here http://code.google.com/p/fsharp-typeclasses/

Comment: You could also use Record types instead of Object types, and leave behind the Interface limitations.

Comment: What does your design achieve that using a record (.e.g, `type Function { Name: string; Derivative: (int -> Function); IsEven: boolean }`) would not? I just don't see the benefit of interfaces here.

Comment: Because adding an additional feature would then force me to implement that fields for that for every function. I'm trying to plan ahead for a situation where I have some functionality going on and maybe 50 different functions defined and I want to add another operation on functions; the situation where I'm hoping for is that the operation can check whether an interface is implemented and if it is, do something and if it isn't don't. Nothing would be broken then if I didn't update (all) of my already defined functions.

Comment: You can add fields to a record without updating every function (you can even pattern match on a subset of fields). You could also use a class.

Comment: yes, but adding fields to a record will still force me to update every of my function definitions, which I might not want to do (for example for some functions it might not make sense to add a property). I want to be able to define another interface and with having the option to implement it for the functions I've defined so far, but not the obligation. Not sure how the class will help, given what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Just added the being able to, but not obliged to have the already defined functions implement an additional interface in the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem that you're trying to solve here is what is called [The Expression Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_problem). You're essentially trying to write code that would be extensible in two directions. Discriminated unions and object-oriented model give you one or the other:

- **Discriminated union** makes it easy to add new operations (just write a function with pattern matching), but it is hard to add a new kind of expression (you have to extend the DU and modify all code
  that uses it).
- **Interfaces** make it easy to add new kinds of expressions (just implement the interface), but it is hard to add new operations (you have to modify the interface and change all code that creates it.

In general, I don't think it is all that useful to try to come up with solutions that let you do both (they end up being terribly complicated), so my advice is to pick the one that you'll need more often.

Going back to your problem, I'd probably represent the function just as a function name together with the parameters:

```
type Expr =
  | Num of decimal
  | Var of string
  | Application of string * Expr list
```

Really - an expression *is* just this. The fact that you can take derivatives is another part of the problem you're solving. Now, to make the derivative extensible, you can just keep a dictionary of the derivatives:

```
 let derrivatives = 
   dict [ "sin", (fun [arg] -> Application("cos", [arg])) 
          ... ]
```

This way, you have an `Expr` type that really models just what an expression *is* and you can write differentiation function that will look for the derivatives in the dictionary.

Comment: Yes, it looks like I'm after a solution to the expression problem indeed. I'm marking your answer as an answer, apart from the string vs IFunction it's basically the backup solution I had in mind. I still think that the solution I was looking for, would be nicer though, because it would keep all function data/properties together in one object as well as make defining additional interfaces in an external library a bit easier. Just for my info, is there a fundamental restriction in .NET why my desired solution is impossible or undesirable?